# Firebase Analytics compliance with ATT on iOS 14.5

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics

If you're using Firebase analytics in your iOS Firebase project, starting in iOS 14.5 do you need to present a prompt asking User for app Tracking permission? From Firebase docs they say that Impact if IDFA is not accessible for Google Analytics:

> Analytics event logging, event reporting, and conversion measurement are unaffected, but attribution is impacted if IDFA is not accessible. To learn more about Google’s response to iOS 14, see our [blog post](https://blog.google/products/ads-commerce/preparing-developers-and-advertisers-for-policy-updates/).

After reading the blog post its still not clear to me if I need to present the prompt or not?

Comment: Does my answer solve this question? if not, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Analytics does not track the user's personal information, most of the information is metadata about the app itself and its usage time. The key difference is you cannot target a specific user and track them as an individual, rather find in general how often users fullfill a specific task.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to track conversions in firebase or google analytics supporting of IDFA is required.

For CocoaPods you use two types of pod:
Either
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
or
pod 'Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport'

The last pod doesn't use IDFA and you shouldn't use ATTrackingManager request to user otherwise should.

If you use FirebaseAnalytics only to track user activity (custom and system events) use AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport and don't show ATTrackingManager prompt.